# Python Pandas Adding to Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have been working on a little pandas work. What I am trying and failing to do is make a simple data quality report. I have a Dataframe with columns that looks like this

```
columns = ['Feature','count', 'Miss.%', 'Card.', 'Min', '1st Qrt.', 'Mean', 'Median', '3rd Qrt', 'Max', 'Std Div']
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=cont_index, columns=columns)
df2.to_csv('/REPORT.csv')
```

I have then run through all the different columns and carried out calculations on each on. This all works and runs fine, the result is a row for each column that contains a value that matches up to the column headings.

`Example, list = ['Income',300,0.0,21,0.0,0.0,2,222, 0.0, 33.98,9,999, 20]`

I am obtaining these values by looping through the different column names and then carrying out the functions for each heading.

What I am having issue with is adding these values into the Dataframe. I simply want to take each row as it is made and then insert it one by one into the dataframe. When ever I try the resulting Dataframe isnt correct and the values dont line up correctly and sometimes arnt in the right position

How do I do this?

Comment: are you sure you want to add the statistics into the same dataframe? usually the statistics go into a separate dataframe that is then the source for printing or exporting reports.

Comment: This isnt really anything serious just trying to get to grips with pandas and dataframes and wanting to know how to add rows to a DF

Comment: I tried df2.append(list), but instead of the list entering in horizontally they were all entered in vertically one value under the other and the actual column names of the dataframe had `NaN` under them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df2.loc['new_row'] = list
```

Assuming `'new_row'` is not in `cont_index`.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways to do this:

1.
using [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat)

```
df1 = DataFrame(...)
df2 = df1.groupby(columns).agg({ column : function, ... }).reset_index()
combined = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

2.
using [`append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)

```
df1 = DataFrame(...)
df2 = df1.groupby(columns).agg({ column : function, ... }).reset_index()
combined = df1.append(df2)
```

Here, [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#aggregation) is used to generate the statistics for each each group, where `columns` is a list of columns used to group values. Of course you may generate the two dataframes any way you like.